# How can I create array from two other arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have two arrays with same size.

```
Dim arr1() As String = {"Hello", "world", "I'm", "some", "text"}
Dim arr2() As String = {"Hello2", "world2", "I'm2", "some2", "text2"}
```

I need to create another *one array from these two arrays.

**Edited:**
Something like this.

```
Dim arr3(0) As String = {"Hello", "Hello2"}
Dim arr3(1) As String = {"world", "world2"}
Dim arr3(2) As String = {"I'm", "I'm2"}
Dim arr3(3) As String = {"some", "some2"}
Dim arr3(4) As String = {"text", "text2"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb):

> **Enumerable.Zip(Of TFirst, TSecond, TResult) Method**
>
> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

**Example:**

```
Dim arr1() As String = {"Hello", "world", "I'm", "some", "text"}
Dim arr2() As String = {"Hello2", "world2", "I'm2", "some2", "text2"}

Dim arr3 = arr1.Zip(arr2, Function(a, b) {a, b}).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **Enumerable.Zip**

```
Dim res = arr1.Zip(arr2, Function(a,b) {a,b})
```